# Title format defined with titlesec: How to use it outside \chapter?

Tags: formatting, titlesec

I am using `titlesec` to define the format of my chapter titles, for instance:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\LARGE\bfseries}
```

I would like to be able to specify the same format (i.e., extract the `\LARGE\bfseries` bit) for a portion of normal text.

Motivation: I am typesetting an anthology where one of the authors occasionally starts a new chapter alongside a figure, in a table, inbetween paragraphs, and so on. So while most of my chapters start on a new page and I don't want to change the default, I need to "fake" a new chapter in several places. My idea is to set it with font defined by `\titleformat`, increment counters if necessary (the book does not have numbered chapters so probably not) and add to contents with `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: So what you want is a nobreak chapter and a regular chapter, but the nobreak chapter is otherwise identical to a regular chapter?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution. It defines a `\nobreakchapter` command that behaves just like `\chapter` but suppresses the pagebreak.   To do this I've created a boolean `\ifnbchap` which gets set to true by the `\nobreakchapter`. Then this boolean is used inside a patched `\chapter` command to skip the pagebreak code. Since your question is quite sketchy on more details I haven't done anything else to format this type of chapter.  I reset the `\nbchap` conditional to false using the `titlesec` end code, so that you can use that conditional to also affect any formatting requirements (e.g. vertical spacing) you might need for the `\nobreakchapter` command.

In response to the comment, I've also eliminated the `\thispagestyle{plain}` command from the `\nobreakchapter` chapters.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\LARGE\bfseries}[\global\nbchapfalse]
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text
\newif\ifnbchap
\xpretocmd{\chapter}{\ifnbchap\else}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\clearpage\fi}{\clearpage\fi\fi}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\ifnbchap\else\thispagestyle{plain}\fi}{}{}
\newcommand{\nobreakchapter}{\nbchaptrue\chapter}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{This is a regular chapter}
\kant
\chapter{This is another regular chapter}
\kant[1]
\nobreakchapter{This is a no break chapter}
\kant[2]
\nobreakchapter{This is another no break chapter}
\kant
\chapter{Another regular chapter}
\kant
\nobreakchapter{A nobreak chapter} 
\kant[1]
\chapter{Another regular chapter}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong but using `\nobreakchapter` suppresses all explicit `\clearpage` commands I have in my code.

Comment: @Frigo You're absolutely right.  Sorry about that. I've revised the code using a conditional which you can then also use within your `titlesec` commands to adjust spacing if needed.  This should now work as you expect.

Comment: This works for me now but opens up a new can of trouble so I won't be using it in my specific case. For instance, since the chapters now start mid-page, I don't want to use the `plain` page style for them. Also `\nobreakchapter` does not stack with `\lettrine`, which I find I need to use in one place.
I think I really need to use just plain text, formatted in the same way as chapter titles.

Comment: @Frigo You gave so little information in your question, this is the result. I've added code to change fix the `pagestyle` problem.  If you want to solve the `lettrine` problem, ask a new question with a minimal working document using my code and linking to this question which clearly shows the `lettrine` problem.